# Unable to set cookie if it does not already exist in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie for a site if it does not exist. It is not working.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['about'])){
  $_COOKIE['about'] += 1;
}
if(!isset($_COOKIE['about'])){
  setcookie("about", 1, time()+3600);
}
```

I have also tried

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['about'])){ 
  setcookie("about", 1, time()+3600);
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use `setcookie` always, so `setcookie("about",$_COOKIE['about']+1,time()+3600);` but idk

Comment: ill try that really quick and get back to you, as far as i can tell the cookie is not setting at all but lemme double check, thanks.

Comment: thanks! that seems to be working, but !isset does not work, only empty is working for me, shoot it up as an answer so i can give you credit, that is wierd because i swear i did it like that before and it worked for me, but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only read stuff from the `$_COOKIE` superglobal, try setting it normally:

```
setcookie("about",$_COOKIE['about']+1,time()+3600);
```

So all together:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['about'])){
   $_COOKIE['about'] += 1;
}else{
   setcookie("about", 1, time()+3600);
}
```

Note the **else**, you've checked before if the cookie isset, so there is no need to check again as either it is or it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

The `$_COOKIE` superglobal is only available for you to read values from. Writing to it does not update the cookie, since that requires a new Cookie header to be sent to the browser. You would probably be better served by [sessions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) backed by cookies, since PHP allows you to modify the session without explicitly saving/setting the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not sent any information to the user yet as the `setcookie` call is just an alias to `header()` (but with a specific schema to follow). You may have error output disabled and are missing the message, so it appears to work but is failing in the background.

`setcookie` should be one of the first calls on your page, up there with starting a session and setting a `header`.